# My react app doesn't render as expected. Why is this happening?

Tags: reactjs

So, I am learning React (from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLX62G4lc44)) and I am stuck in the beginning.

I set up 2 files: **App.js** and **index.html**, just like in the video.

I installed the npm packages react and react-dom too.

This is the following code of the files;

*index.html* :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src='/App.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*App.js* :

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM  from 'react-dom'

export default ReactDOM.render(<h1>Test</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

- Both files are in the same directory.

But whenever I hit the index.html in the browser it returns me nothing, and I am just following the instructions from the video that I mentioned. Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a lot of configuration necessary for a react app. It is tough to tell what you could be missing, but there is a great tool [create react app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) that has good instructions and lots of options like adding TypeScript.

Comment: But why I can't just follow the instructions from the video? Creat react app is pretty good and I will probably use it further but for now I am looking to solve this particular issue in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the react js file (the framework) in your html file.

From the video, you can see on the left pane the "dependencies" section. It has both react and react-dom as dependencies.

Comment: You mean add this (<script src="../node_modules/react/index.js"></script>) in the head tag? It didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

In your App.js you are trying to export the `ReactDOM.render()` statement.

Try changing it to this

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM  from 'react-dom'

ReactDOM.render(<h1>Test</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I tried this but I got no progress. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your `index.html` file is just HTML and not a React component, then you can't `require` it in the same way you would do with a JS file.

However, if you are using Browserify — there is a transform called [stringify](https://github.com/JohnPostlethwait/stringify) which will allow you to require non-js files as strings. Once you have added the transform, you will be able to require HTML files and they will export as though they were just strings.

Once you have required the HTML file, you'll have to inject the HTML string into your component, using the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```
var __html = require('./index.html');
var index= { __html: __html };

React.module.exports = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={index} />
    );
  }
});
```

This technique goes against a lot of what React is about though. It would be more natural to create your templates as React components with JSX, rather than as regular HTML files.